# Удаление или передублирование префабоф

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю аналог игры Дудл джамп. Если делать с однотипной платформой, все работает идеально(По другому коду). я решил заморочиться и сделать заменяемые платформы. сами платформы это пустышки с коллайдером, а к ним я пытаюсь подключить префабы самих платформ. при запуске, базовые платформы сразу же появляются, при игре, пустышки снизу переносятся на верх и рандомно располагаются по экрану, но сами префабы не получается удалять и переносить наверх.
[image: Запуск]

[image: Генерация]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GeneratorPlats : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject[] objects;
public GameObject[] PtatfColl;
public float verh = 0.5f;
private int fig;

void Update()
{

}
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)       
{

}
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    //Destroy(objects[fig]);
    if (collision.tag == "TGD" )              
        {
        
        int plat = Random.Range(1, 90);
           if (plat <= 30)
           {
               fig = 0;
           }
           if (plat > 30 && plat <= 60)
           {
               fig = 1;
           }
           if (plat > 60 && plat <= 90)
           {
               fig = 2;
           }

        StArTpLaTfOrMs();
        }
}
public void StArTpLaTfOrMs()
{
   
    int r = Random.Range(0, 39);
    switch (r)
    {
        case 0:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1.8f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 1:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 2:
            transform.position = new Vector3(0.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 3:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 4:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.95f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 5:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1.8f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 6:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 7:
            transform.position = new Vector3(0.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 8:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 9:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.95f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 10:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1.8f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 11:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 12:
            transform.position = new Vector3(0.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 13:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 14:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.95f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 15:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1.8f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 16:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 17:
            transform.position = new Vector3(0.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 18:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 19:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.95f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 20:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1.8f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 21:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 22:
            transform.position = new Vector3(0.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 23:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 24:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.95f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 25:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1.8f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 26:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 27:
            transform.position = new Vector3(0.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 28:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 29:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.95f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 30:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1.8f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 31:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 32:
            transform.position = new Vector3(0.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 33:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 34:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.95f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 35:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1.8f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 36:
            transform.position = new Vector3(-1f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 37:
            transform.position = new Vector3(0.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 38:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.15f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;
        case 39:
            transform.position = new Vector3(1.95f, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
            Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            break;


    }
   }
  }
```

Может я описал данный вопрос не совсем корректно, но надеюсь весьма понятно, Что посоветуете господа программисты?

Answer (score 1):

Я не отвечу на сам вопрос ибо влом разбираться в чем его суть.... Но посмею оптимизировать ужас написанный в коде... Я на эту жесть без слез смотреть не могу

(оптимизации коснулись обоих методов)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GeneratorPlats : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objects;
    public GameObject[] PtatfColl;
    public float verh = 0.5f;
    private int fig;

    private float[] positions = {-1.8f, -1f, 0.15f}; //здесь все 39 значений

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        //Destroy(objects[fig]);

        CreatePlatform(collision);
    }

    public void CreatePlatform(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag != "TGD" ) return;
        
        int plat = Random.Range(1, 90);

        if (plat > 60) {
            fig = 2;
        }
        else if (plat > 30){
            fig = 1;
        }
        else {
            fig = 0;
        }
    
        InstantiatePlatform();
    }

    private void InstantiatePlatform()
    {
        int spawnPos = positions[ Random.Range(0, positions.length) ];

        transform.position = new Vector3(spawnPos, transform.position.y +13f, 0);
        Instantiate(objects[fig], PtatfColl[0].transform.position - new Vector3(0.156f, verh, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

а сам вопрос переформулируй, а то не понятно ничего